# How to select desired columns in Datastage when doing an direct extract-load?

Tags: file, loading, flat, datastage

How do I select desired columns from one flat file to another flat file using Datastage.
I have a source file containing two fields called NAME and ROLL_NO. Now i need to select only NAME field to my target flat file using Datastage with out using any stages in between.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by only putting the NAME column in the Source stages Output columns.  I performed an example to test this:

First, I created an InputFile.txt file, with the following records:

```
Caitlyn Stark,1
Eddard Stark,2
Hodor,3
Bran Stark,4
```

Using Datastage 8.5 Server Job:

I created two Sequential File stages naming them InputStage and OutputStage.  In the InputStage's Output Tab, the Columns sub tab, define only the first column, 'Names'.  If you dont need ROLL_NO in the second file, then dont pull it out of the first file.

Output file looked like this:

```
Caitlyn Stark
Eddard Stark
Hodor
Bran Stark
```

It is important to note that Datastage is an ETL program, that is 'Extract-Transform-Load'.  Extracting and Loading directly is supported, but you are going to have severe limitations. Such as, if you wanted to pull the ROLL_NO field, but not the NAME field, you would HAVE to include a Transformer Stage.  Transformer stages are the meat of the ETL sandwich, and you should plan on using at least one per server job in most cases.

The transformer stage is important because it allows you to remap from source to destination.  You can change column ordering, exclude columns, or generate new columns based on variables, hard coded text, etc.